# Python erro 535, Incorrect authentication data para envio de email (Resolvido)

Tags: python, email

Bom dia, minha aplicação já hospedada e funcionando ate a semana passada, começou a apresentar este erro: 535, 'Incorrect authentication data' no momento em que é solicitado o envio do e-mail.

A primeira vista diria que é um problema de login ou senha porem ao utilizar o mesmo código na minha maquina local obtenho o sucesso no envio, também realizei testes em outras maquinas de desenvolvimento. Utilizei dois servidores de e-mail diferentes respeitando as configurações de smtp, tls/ssl e porta, novamente em minha maquina obtenho o sucesso mas na aplicação já hospedada o erro é sempre o mesmo.

A unica coisa que localizei de diferente foi o IP aonde a aplicação esta hospedada, é um IP com "localização" fora do Brasil, verifiquei se o IP se encontrava em uma black-list e os mesmos estão limpos.Utilizei uma conta de empresa no Gmail,uma conta na Localweb e uma conta de empresa no Office365 com os mesmos resultados
Qualquer ajuda orientação é bem vinda.

Segue o código utilizado para envio:

```
def envio(self, para, assunto, corpo):
        try:
            fromaddr = "meuemail@meudominio.com.br"
            toaddr = para
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = fromaddr
            msg['To'] = toaddr
            msg['Subject'] = assunto
            body = corpo
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
            s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
            s.starttls()
            s.login(fromaddr, "minha_senha")
            text = msg.as_string()
            s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
            s.quit()
            return True
        except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
            print(e)
            return False
```

Comment: João, bom dia! Já tentou modificar a porta do smtp para 465 por exemplo?

Comment: Imonferrari, por via das duvidas realizei o teste e trava não obtenho resposta do servidor smtp bem na linha s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 465) - como você sugeriu.

Comment: A informação estava indo então. Possivelmente a autenticação smtp está desativada. Você deve autorizar o usuário que irá enviar os e-mails no painel de administração da microsoft. [Link](https://admin.microsoft.com/)

Comment: Desculpe, mas não compreendi.
quando envio o comando:
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)

O usuário ainda nem foi informado.
Parece mais que aporta 465 esta fechada.
Toda a via tenho acesso para alterar configurações da microsoft mas não localizei nada do tipo, poderia me passar mas detalhes ?
Obrigado

Comment: Possivelmente ele mostra que o erro está naquela linha pois ela é que contem a porta 'errada'. `s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)` quando você chama essa linha de código você passa a porta como parâmetro também.  `'fromaddr` é o email de quem está enviando o e-mail, você deve autorizar este e-mail para autenticar. https://admin.microsoft.com/ -> Users -> Active users. Você vai na parte de aplicativos de email e autoriza o usuário.

Comment: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)

Comment: Entendi, e antes de mais nada meu muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.
Entrei nas configurações conforme suas instruções mas todos os itens ja estavam marcados (permitidos). Com novos testes o erro mudou para "Connection unexpectedly closed".
Consigo dar um ping no smtp, acredito que não seja firewall neste caso.

Comment: Tente usar `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()` no lugar de `smtplib.SMTP()`.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, o problema foi solucionado.
Acionei o local que hospeda a minha aplicação, não fui informado quais providencias eles tomaram, ou o que foi realizado, mas os envios de e-mail voltaram ao norma.
Agradeço ao Imonferrari pela paciência e ajuda e apenas para não deixar no vacuo, na tentativa de usar o smtplib.SMTP_SLL() o erro voltou ao 535, 'Incorrect authentication data'.
Imagino que isso signifique que era um firewall ou outra configuração que foi aplicada fora do código.

Comment: Que bom que solucionou! Abraço!!